# How to create datatable with columnname , datatypes and few data in R?

Tags: r, datatable

I was wondering if I can create `DataTable` containing 4 columns. "Column Name","Data Type" "top 5" and "last5" data ? Basically, converting `str(df)` output into datatable. Not sure if there is package available for this task. If there is please point to that package.

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help:

Let's say your `data` looks like this

```
data = data.frame(
  x1 = sample(letters,20),
  x2 = sample(1:100,20)
)
```

Then, you can create a DataTable with your five columns like this:

```
data.table(
  ColumnName = colnames(data),
  DataType = sapply(data,typeof),
  first5 = lapply(data,head,5),
  last5 = lapply(data,tail,5)
)
```

Output:

```
   ColumnName  DataType         first5          last5
1:         x1 character      x,w,p,c,n      h,k,z,t,f
2:         x2   integer 24,26,20,72, 1 45,25,18,80,54
```